# Marcar um campo checkbox, se uma ou duas opções forem escolhidas no campo select

Tags: select, checkbox

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho um campo de seleção com 4 opções.
Se for escolhido a opção 1, quero que marque um campo checkbox (BRANCO)

Como faço

Comment: Julio, considere colocar mais detalhes na sua pergunta, dessa forma que você colocou fica difícil ajudar

Comment: PERGUNTA ALTERADA !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta com um JS tipo isso

```
$('select[name="opcoes"]').on('change', function(){
  $('.checks').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
  if($(this).val() !== ''){
    $('input[data-id="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop('checked', true);  
  }
});
```

Fiz um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evandrobm/xpvt214o/889029/) pra demonstrar

Comment: Muito bom !!!!!

Comment: @JúlioRicardo Não esquece de marcar a resposta como correta, assim tu ajuda outras pessoas no futuro que tenham o mesmo problema no futuro

Comment: ;-)........... !